# The closure of a set as intersection of sum of two sets

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a normed vector space over $K\;(\Bbb R\;\text{or }\Bbb C)$ and let $\;A\subset X$ then a I want to prove that:
$$\bar A = \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)$$
So, my attempt for the $\;(\supseteq)\;$ goes like this:

Let $y\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)$
$$\Rightarrow\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\; y=a_n+x_n,\;a\in A\;\land\;x_n\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\\
\Rightarrow\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\; y-x_n=a_n\;(\in A)$$
so we have a sequence $\{y-x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $A$ s.t. $\{y-x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}y,\;$ since $\|(y-x_n)-y\|=\|x_n\|<\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Thus $y\in\bar A$, and thereby $\;\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)\subseteq \bar A.$

Now for the $\;(\subseteq)\;$:
Let $\;y\in \bar A,\;$ so there exists a sequence $\;\{y_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ in $\;A\;$ s.t. $\;\{y_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}y\;$
$$\Rightarrow \{y-y_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$
in particular, we have that
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\;\|y-y_n\|<\frac{1}{n}\\
\Rightarrow \forall n\in\Bbb N\;\;(y-y_n)\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)$$
and, by Minkowski operations, we get that
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\;y\in y_n+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\\
\Rightarrow \forall n\in\Bbb N\;\; y=y_n+x_n,\;\;\text{where }\;y_n\in A\land x_n\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\\
\Rightarrow \forall n\in\Bbb N\;\; y\in A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\\
\Rightarrow y\in \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)$$
thus
$$\bar A\subseteq \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)$$
and hence
$$\bar A=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \big(A+B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)\big)$$
What do you think? Did I miss something?